# Text missing in email body when adding attachment to email

Tags: arrays, email, pdf, text, attachment

I have problem when adding an attachment to email, when sending without attachment everything is ok, but when I add attachment, text in email body missing, in 'quick view' in gmail is shown, but when open the email, there is no text,

can somebody help ? thanks

```
Path pdfFilePath = Paths.get(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/" + PdfName + ".pdf"); //File path
                        byte[] pdfByteArray = Files.readAllBytes(pdfFilePath );


                        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

                        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(SenderAddress));
                        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                InternetAddress.parse(RecipientAddress));
                        message.setSubject(Subject);
                        message.setFileName(PdfName + ".pdf");
                        //MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
                        //message.setContent(attachment, "application/pdf");

                        DataSource dataSrc = new ByteArrayDataSource(pdfByteArray, "application/pdf");
                        message.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(dataSrc));
                        message.setText(MailBodyText);

                        Transport.send(message);
```

[[gmail quick view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBlF7.png)]
[[opened email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uK6js.png)]()